# How to have 2 Github SSH accesses?

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh, git

I have a personal account *ericpersonal* and a company account *ericcompanyabc* (they forced me to even though they could have add my personal GitHub account to their repos) on github.com.
I'm using a computer the company gives and spend more time on work projects so I'm primarily logged in as *ericcompanyabc*

I then generated 2 private and public keys as a result:

```
❯ ls -lrt ~/.ssh
total 72
-rw-------  1 eric.nguyen  eric.nguyen   110 Aug 31 11:03 authorized_keys.jcorig
-rw-r--r--  1 eric.nguyen  eric.nguyen  2004 Sep 13 14:16 known_hosts
lrwxr-xr-x  1 eric.nguyen  eric.nguyen    76 Sep 25 21:53 ssh_auth_sock -> /var/folders/c3/q4dw0_q90lj6_nysk_hjt8p00000gn/T//ssh-31QAwZUf1Pmz/agent.501
-rw-------  1 eric.nguyen  eric.nguyen   743 Oct 26 16:02 id_rsa2.pub
-rw-------  1 eric.nguyen  eric.nguyen  3243 Oct 26 16:02 id_rsa2
-rw-r--r--  1 eric.nguyen  eric.nguyen   746 Oct 27 16:29 id_rsa1.pub
-rw-------  1 eric.nguyen  eric.nguyen  3243 Oct 27 16:29 id_rsa1
-rw-r--r--  1 eric.nguyen  eric.nguyen   279 Oct 27 16:29 config
-rw-------  1 eric.nguyen  eric.nguyen   225 Nov  3 17:57 authorized_keys
```

I have to switch between the 2 accounts using the following commands but it's very tedious:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa1
```

I've also tried using `.ssh/config` file but no success

```
❯ cat ~/.ssh/config 
Host githubcompany
    HostName github.com
    User git
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa1
    UseKeychain yes

Host githuberic
    HostName github.com
    User git
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes
```

What can I do to make switching between Github accounts seamless?

I'm using macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: It’s almost like you need two user accounts and to `su` between them with distinct prompts and environments. I wonder if shell functions could swap the variables needed - `foo work` and `foo home`

Comment: good idea, `alias gitpersonal=eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa2` would suffice

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution for me is to avoid ever switching my identity, so I don't have to automate the changing of the environment variables and files that provide the identity to the shell:

1. Set up GitHub SSH for your work GitHub account e.g. *ericcompanyabc*.
2. Next, on my personal GitHub repos, I simply add *ericcompanyabc* as a **collaborator**. Voila, I can now push to my personal projects (as *ericcompanyabc* on the company's computer) without having to switch GitHub account back and forth.

(granting *ericpersonal* access to work repos is impossible here of course)